# combine two forloops for get database values in same line

Tags: python

am using two forloop for get values from database

```
{% for marvar in marks  %}
<h3> <tr> {{ marvar.exam }} : </tr> </h3>
{% endfor %}
{% for examall in exams %}
<h3> {{ examall.exam }} : </h3>
{% endfor %}
```

i want to use combine ..this for loops

like example :

```
for x,y in zip([1,2,3],[1,2,3]):
    print(x,y)
```

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

if i did like

```
for x,y in zip([marvar],[examall]):
   print(x,y)
```

it gives "Could not parse the remainder" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's template language is purposely simple, because you're not meant to do anything overly complex in the templates.

Format your data in the view, and then pass the resulting structure to the template:

```
# views.py
marks_and_exams = zip(marks, exams)

# template
{% for mark, exam in marks_and_exams %}
    {{mark}} {{exam}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
 for x,y in zip(marks,exams):
    print(x,y)
```